Is it valid to nest forms using shadow DOM in custom web components?
I have a question about custom web components. Custom element for example:
class CustomButton extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.root = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
        const form = document.createElement("form");
        this.root.append(form);
    }
}
customElements.define("custom-button", CustomButton);

Now I put this custom element which contains own form with some inputs into another form in page
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <custom-button>Select</custom-button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

In this case, web component is universal library component and I have I have no control over where the user puts it.
Normally I can't put <form> element into another <form> element but what about shadow dom in this case? Is it valid? Can i put anything into shadow dom without having to worry about some specific usage?
Thanks for any response!
